# How to create a strike through UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Is it possible to create a button with strike through text without using an image?

I know it's possible to do it to a `UILabel`

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your String here"];
[attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                        value:@2
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];
```

Comment: [`- [UIButton setAttributedTitle:forState:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setAttributedTitle:forState:)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the title for the button using `setAttributedTitle:forState:` passing in the attributed string you created.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
[button setAttributedTitle:attributeString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setAttributedTitle:attributeString forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let attributes = [NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName : 1]
    let title = NSAttributedString(string: "YOUR STRING", attributes: attributes)

    button.setAttributedTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a mutable attributed string with Strike Through Attribute and set this attributed string to button's attributed text. Used attributeString code snippet from above @grabury question.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton alloc] init];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your Text Here"];
    [attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                            value:@2
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];
button.titleLabel.attributedText = attributeString;
```

Thanks.